# C# Path Ellipsis without Win32 API call

Tags: c#, .net, path, ellipsis

I have a long path I'd like to shorten for displaying on a form using the ellipsis character(s?).

I know there is the [`PathCompactPathEx`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.pathcompactpathex) Win32 API call, but I know there is a built-in .NET equivalent. I have used it previously, but cannot find it any more. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own link has

> Alternative Managed API:
>   `System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(String, Font, Size, TextFormatFlags.ModifyString | TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis);`

at the bottom. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You were faster. `TextRenderer.DrawText()` to render it accordingly.

Comment: Errr, yes. How embarrassing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the ModifyString flag in versions of .Net since (at least) version 3.5 exposes an ugly and [potentially dangerous bug discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640410/add-ellipsis-to-a-path-in-a-winforms-program-without-win32-api-call-revisited).

Hans Passant found the [correct way to do this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397860/c-winforms-smart-textbox-control-to-auto-format-path-length-based-on-textbox-w).