# list view column text manupulation on resizing

Tags: c#

I have a list view and there are multiple columns with long text values, like a column with destination file path it has a value like `c:\users\kavya\new\coding\img1000.jpg`
something very big.

I want to adjust the text according to size of the column when the users uses the scroll bar:
with width something very big all the data `c:\users\kavya\new\coding\img1000.jpg`
should be visible and when he scrolls the column header to very small only the `c:\img1000.jpg` has to be viewed but the memory should have the entire path
actualy we see something like `c:\users\kavya…..`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think this word is called `ellipsis`.  this can be avoid by disabling ellipsis in properties. i am not sure.

Comment: is there a way i can only view the drive and file name if the column width is decreased so that the actual filename is visible but the memory should have entire path....

Answer (score 1):

By doing Windows API call PathCompactPathEx,

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 static extern bool PathCompactPathEx([Out] StringBuilder pszOut, string szPath, int cchMax, int dwFlags);

static string PathShortener(string path, int length)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     PathCompactPathEx(sb, path, length, 0);
     return sb.ToString();
 }
```

**OR** You can try like this :

```
string PathShortener(string path)
 {
     const string pattern = @"^(\w+:|\\)(\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\).*(\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+)$";
     const string replacement = "$1$2...$3";
     if (Regex.IsMatch(path, pattern))
     {
         return Regex.Replace(path, pattern, replacement);
     }
     else
     {
         return path;
     }          
 }
```

**OR** You can use like below :

```
string ellipsisedPath = OriginalPath + '\0';
```

visit: [Add Ellipsis to a Path in a WinForms Program without Win32 API call (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640410/add-ellipsis-to-a-path-in-a-winforms-program-without-win32-api-call-revisited)

Comment: sir you have given how to get the required string from entire path but i want how to manage the column width based on the text visible......

Comment: based on the column header scrolled the text visible changes i want  the total text visible at a particular column width and when it is small only c:/filename visible . how to manage column width and text visible in list view